# Scale an SVG object along a user-defined axis in Illustrator

Tags: scaling, adobe-illustrator

I have an object (see orange arc below) within an SVG that I would like to scale along the axis of the object itself.

I know the "Transform" options in Illustrator allow you to scale along the X or Y axis, but that doesn't work for me. I want to scale the object such that at each cross-section of the arc (depicted as the black lines in the photo), the object is exactly 10% of the width of the original. Therefore, the axis that I want to scale along is the hypothetical curved line which passes perpendicularly through all of the black lines in the photo.

If done correctly, this should reduce the X and Y dimensions of the object only slightly, but will reduce the orange-colored area to be 10% of the original.

[image]

Comment: This question may be better suited to https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ and showing what the expected result is would also be useful

Comment: It depends on what exactly you're doing, probably the 'Constrain angle' option can help. It rotates the X and Y axis on arbitrary angle: http://vectips.com/tips-and-tricks/did-you-know-constrain-angle/

Comment: @YuriKhristich looks like that tool sets a single angle for the entire object - but the angle I'm working with changes along the length of the arc. It would be ok if I could specify that the axis is curved, but it looks like Illustrator expects x and y axes to be straight lines.

Comment: Probably it will need some workaround. Is see no way to do it directly with the native tools. Solution will depend on what you trying to do exactly. What the object? What the result should look like? It could be a blend of start and end objects with 10 steps where first step is 10% 'scaled' object. Etc.